# E/FrameEvents( 6080): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame. how can i fix this?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, openstreetmap

aslo the indicated location cannot displayed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdNJm.png)
**I set:**
min sdk 21.
compile sdk 34.
**also give this permission: **
**ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  --- ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION --- INTERNET
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE  --- WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ---
android:usesCleartextTraffic=true**

**here is my code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_osm_plugin/flutter_osm_plugin.dart';

void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   title: 'Flutter Demo',
   theme: ThemeData(
     colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
     useMaterial3: true,
   ),
   home: const MapScreen(),
 );
}
}

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const MapScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<MapScreen> createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
MapController controller = MapController(
                         initPosition: GeoPoint(latitude: 47.4358055, longitude: 8.4737324),
         );
@override
void dispose() {
 // TODO: implement dispose
 super.dispose();
 controller.dispose();
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: Stack(
     children: [
       OSMFlutter(
           controller: controller,
           osmOption: OSMOption(
             userTrackingOption: const UserTrackingOption(
               enableTracking: true,
               unFollowUser: true,
             ),
             zoomOption: const ZoomOption(
               initZoom: 15,
               minZoomLevel: 3,
               maxZoomLevel: 15,
               stepZoom: 1.0,
             ),
             userLocationMarker: UserLocationMaker(
               personMarker: const MarkerIcon(
                 icon: Icon(
                   Icons.person_pin_circle,
                   color: Colors.red,
                   size: 48,
                 ),
               ),
               directionArrowMarker: const MarkerIcon(
                 icon: Icon(
                   Icons.double_arrow,
                   size: 48,
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             roadConfiguration: const RoadOption(
               roadColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
             ),
             markerOption: MarkerOption(
                 defaultMarker: const MarkerIcon(
               icon: Icon(
                 Icons.person_pin_circle,
                 color: Colors.blue,
                 size: 56,
               ),
             )),
           ))
     ],
   ),
 );
}
}
```

This is the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pvAx.png)

i want to solve this problem. how can i fix it?